# How to add values to a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a list of States

```
states = ['Arizona','New York']
```

and another list of dates

```
dates = ['2020-04-05','2020-01-02','2020-03-28']
```

My programming is outputting some values based on states and each date. I want my final output in the form of a nested dictionary

```
out = {'Arizona': {'2020-04-05':15, '2020-01-02':30, '2020-03-28':50}, 'New York': {'2020-04-05':15, '2020-01-02':100, '2020-03-28':75}}
```

The values 15,30,50,100,75 are the outputs generated from the code.

Note: The output values are extracted from a data frame and the number of states and dates will vary as per user choice

Comment: Where did `15,30,50,100,75` values come from?

Comment: @MrNobody33 I wanted to ask the same thing

Comment: These are outputs from my code

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want to achieve the given output which is a nested dictionary and the main keys should be the states and the inside them we have another dictionary with dates as keys and corresponding output from codes as values

Comment: @aaradhy yes, but where are the corresponding outputs coming from? Where are they stored?

Comment: @HarshalParekh the outputs are coming from the code I have written, in which I have iterated over states and dates and extracted the corresponding value from my data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dates = ['2020-04-05','2020-01-02','2020-03-28']
states = ['Arizona','New York']  
out = dict()
    
for s in states:
    out[s] = dict()
    for d in dates:
        out[s][d] = 0    # put your corresponding output here instead of 0

print(out)
```

Output:

```
{'Arizona': {'2020-04-05': 0, '2020-01-02': 0, '2020-03-28': 0}, 'New York': {'2020-04-05': 0, '2020-01-02': 0, '2020-03-28': 0}}
```

1. Create an outer dictionary.
2. Then iterating on the states, create a new dictionary for each state.
3. Then iterating on the dates, put the date as key and your value for each date.